# How to print UTF8 cookie value in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, cookies, utf-8

is it possible and if yes how do I print an UTF-8 string stored in cookie in JSP? I am able to URI encode it and save it in the cookie using javascript, but I can't seem to decode it afterwards, right now I'm printing it using EL statements.

PS: If any code sample is needed, I will post it, but right now I don't know what part would be helpful.

Comment: JavaScript, Java, and JSP? Are you sure you need all those language tags?

Comment: Well, it's my first question ever, sorry if I used too much, thought it's better to put them there